# Can Leaflet ZXY tiles be used in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, web-mapping, tiles, tilecache, amazon-s3

I have created tiles from a drone flight, loaded them onto Amazon S3 storage and used them in a leaflet web page served from an AWS EC2 instance.    That is all working fine.  I would my desktop QGIS 3.10 application like to use the same tiles stored on the S3 bucket in ZXY folders.

I tried to ust the XYZ Tiles point to the directory URL similar to this => `https://my-maps.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/MAP1/2020/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.   This does not work because I probably need a tile server running there.

I do not really want to have 2 copies of the map on different sites if I can do it from one spot.  Is there a way for QGIS 3 to use these tiles from Amazon S3 bucket storage?

Reference 1: `https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304483/is-it-possible-to-serve-vector-tiles-directly-from-s3`

Reference 2: `https://github.com/addresscloud/serverless-tiles`

[image]

Comment: will this work? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis/217670#217670

Comment: DPSSpatial - That is what I have been trying.  I think I would have to have a tile server on there maybe?   I did i go that post and no dice.

Comment: Jeff on our team thought this might help: https://www.maptiler.com/news/2018/03/map-service-for-qgis3-without-a-server/ He's been doing work with vector tiles served to qgis